# How to blink table row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found one sample where CSS is used to blink a table row but I do not want to use CSS. Instead I want to use jQuery. Here is the sample I've got:

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}

.blink {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: blink;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-direction: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: blink;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='odd blink'>
    <td>First row, very important.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='odd'>
    <td>Third row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fourth row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='odd'>
    <td>Fifth row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='blink'>
    <td>Sixth row, also important</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/mc2fb8ag/

Please tell me how to get the same nice table row flashing effect with jQuery.

Comment: Why do you not want to use css?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you use CSS for this as it's much better suited to amending the UI - not least of all because it's hardware accelerated whereas JS is not.

Comment: Css animation is best and better than other . why you are going for jquery?

Comment: If you think this is messy, you can remove all parts with the veerdor prefix (`-webkit-`, `-moz-` etc), as that is no longer required

Comment: The CSS example shown isn't "blinking", it's doing a slow fade in/fade out - is that what you want, or do you actually want it to blink?
 Anyway, jQuery does have a number of time-based animation methods, so using a couple of those with a little pseudo-recursion would do the trick.